# session_store :active_record_store options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, activerecord

Wanted to know the meaning of the :secret and :key options while configuring the session_store. So, for example I have a config like the following:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, 
    {:key => '_my_app_session', :secret => '5xb5x1g92e965b95b16e49x79gxx9999', :expire_after => 2.hours}
```

what would the :secret and :key options do here? I googled but not many answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure those options are only valid if you're using the cookie session store (rather than the active record session store). The key is the name of the cookie which contains the session data, and the secret is the value used to encrypt/decrypt the data stored in the cookie.

Answer (score -1):

**Active Record Session Store:**

"The serializer may be one of marshal, json, or hybrid. marshal is the default and uses the built-in Marshal methods coupled with Base64 encoding. json does what it says on the tin, using the parse() and generate() methods of the JSON module. hybrid will read either type but write as JSON."

Adding: `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.serializer = :json` to config/application.rb solved the issue for me.